# Matrix multiplication of $4 \times 1$ matrix with $4 \times 4$ matrix

Tags: matrices

I'm new to matrix multiplication and just wondered how I would evaluate the following:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1& 0 & 0 \\
-1& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and even:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c & d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1& 0 & 0 \\
-1& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: In that order, you can't: the number of columns of the first matrix must be the number of rows of the second.

Comment: Fixed. How would I evaluate it?

Comment: When evaluating matrix products by hand I find it helpful to write them as follows: \begin{align} & \begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1& 0 & 0 \\
-1& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix}
d \\
c \\
-b \\
-a \\
\end{pmatrix}\end{align} it makes the row-column products easier to do (or at least it works for me)

Comment: It's a dot product of each row of the first matrix by each column of the second matrix. Hence the result will be a $4\times 1$ column vector in the first case, and  a $1\times 4$ row vector in the second case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a formula to compute the $(i, j)$th entry of $C = AB$ (provided the sizes of $A$ and $B$ match): assume $A$ is $n \times p$ and $B$ is $p \times m$, then $C$ is $n \times m$, and 
$$c_{i, j} = \sum_{k = 1}^p a_{\color{red}{i}k}b_{k\color{red}{j}}.$$
Take your first question for example, the result should be a $4 \times 1$ matrix, it is quite straightforward to compute as follows:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & -1& 0 & 0 \\
-1& 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a \\
b \\
c \\
d \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
0 \times a + 0 \times b + 0 \times c + 1 \times d \\
0 \times a + 0 \times b + 1 \times c + 0 \times d \\
0 \times a + (-1) \times b + 0 \times c + 0 \times d \\
(-1) \times a + 0 \times b + 0 \times c + 0 \times d 
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
d \\
c \\
-b \\
-a
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: What about the other case given in the question? Is that exactly the same?

Comment: No, the size is different. Remember that the size of a multiplication of an $n \times p$ matrix and $p \times m$ matrix is $n \times m$.